# Render don't start in blender while using Cycles

Tags: rendering, render, blender

I just appended two blender files to get my two models in one scene. when I hit Render Image. It doesn't start rendering although before appending the two files the render was working properly. I tried to render the default scene(Cube scene) in blender and it rendered. I guess the problem is not with my camera because I created a new camera and made it my active camera and still not working. all the objects appear in the viewport shading and none of them are hidden.
one more thing the GPU compute option is no longer active besides it was active before and worked with me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out the problem. the sequencer in the output properties was checked on. to check it off go to Output Properties > Post Processing > Sequencer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to add my solution which bugged my mind an hour ago:

Blender has two options for rendering, which confused me at first, and might confuse others as well.

`Render` -> `View Render` will view the previous rendered image. However, if you've just opened Blender, then there's no previously rendered image of your viewport.

In order to render the viewport, you'll have to tap `Render` -> `Render Image` first. Then at a later stage you can do `Render` -> `View Render` to view that image.

I guess the same works for animations as well, first you'll need to do `Render` -> `Render Animation` to render your animation, then later do `Render` -> `View Animation`.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem. Disabling the sequencer, as OP mentioned, didn't do anything. For me the problem was in the output path for animation; in Output Properties > Output.

My destination folder was moved (it was a very old project) and Blender seems to have no problem with rendering images to a folder that does not exist. However this is not the case with animation. I imagine that when rendering animation, blender uses the target folder to store rendered frames and when everything is rendered, takes the frames and makes the animation.
I do not have any insight into how blender works nor do I have experience with programming so take this as an uneducated guess.

;TLDR:
Check your destination folder, blender seems to be fine with rendering images to non existent folders. This is not the case with animations.